# $f_n(x)=x^{n-1} \cdot e^{1/x}$ Show that $\frac{d^nf_n(x)}{dx^n}=\frac{-1^nf_n(x)}{x^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f_n(x)=x^{n-1} \cdot e^{1/x}$. Show that $\frac{d^nf_n(x)}{dx^n}=\frac{-1^nf_n(x)}{x^{2n}}$.

Base case is checked.

$f_{n+1}(x)=x\cdot f_n(x)$
.

Induction hypothesis assumed.

$\frac{d^nf_{n+1}(x)}{dx^n}$.

$\frac{d^nf_{n+1}(x)}{dx^n} = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}[x \cdot f_n(x)]$ which when I continue I am getting really messy things.

Comment: You've defined $f_n$, but not $f$.

Comment: Thanks,edited!.

Comment: So assuming the remaining $f$ is also $f_n$, you want to prove $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^{n-1}e^{1/x}=(-1)^nx^{-n-1}e^{1/x}$?

Comment: Yes this is the same question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199840/calculus-the-nth-derivative-of-y-n-xn-1e1-x

Comment: Why did you duplicate it?

Comment: I am doing induction proof which isn't covered in that post.

Comment: Right, so it has to be induction for your purposes, OK.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D:=\frac{d}{dx}$. If you find this calculation messy, perhaps you're unaware of the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), which implies$$D^{n+1}f_{n+1}=D^{n+1}(xf_n)=xD^{n+1}f_{n+1}+nD^nf_n=(xD+n)D^nf_n.$$For the inductive step, verify$$(xD+k+1)(-1)^kx^{-k-1}e^{1/x}=(-1)^{k+1}x^{-k-2}e^{1/x}.$$